# Modules that Have been installed in PIP not appearing in PyCharm via the import function

Tags: python, module, pip, python-module

I have recently started learning Python using PyCharm on Windows 10. I am trying to use PIP to install modules (I have tried Pillow, Pygame and randomword). When I try to install these, PIP says that I was successful and the module comes up when I use `Pip freeze`. However When I try to import them into Pycharm using the `from import` function. The module is not found. I cannot locate the module in the LIB folder as well. What do I need to do to have these modules appear in python,
Many Thanks,

Comment: Could you show us how you're using `import`?

Comment: Check if your pycharm project is using a virtual environment, if so run pip install from the pycharm terminal instead of your usual terminal. If that does not do it, you may try in pycharm > File > "Invalidate Caches/restart"

Answer (score 0):

**Did you make sure you installed the module with the right pip?**

I mean, many people with have more than one python editor installed, and so, there will be multiple pips.

If you installed a module with the pip from IDLE-3.8, the module will only be installed for that IDLE-3.8.